# What is the difference between first-class entities and second-class entities in perl?

Tags: perl

What is defined by the saying "first-class entities" and how does it differ from "second-class entities"?

What does it mean when one says "regexes are first-class entities in modern perl when created with the qr// operator" (taken from Modern Perl: the book).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As MeNoMore correctly said, a first-class-entity is a data type of the language you can freely assign to variables etc. In Perl, these include:

- Scalars
- Arrays
- Hashes
- Coderefs (e.g. anonymous subroutines)
- IO
- Typeglobs (The symbol table is a hash of globs)
- Formats

Those can reside in the symbol table. The scalar slot can be occupied by various other types in addition:

- Signed integers
- Unsigned integers
- Floating point numbers
- Strings
- References
- Regexes

Some of these entities have built-in constructors into tha language: Number and String literals for scalars, list notation for arrays and hashes, `[]` and `{}` for anonymous array- and hashrefs, the `sub` keyword for code, the `open` function for IO objects, the `format` builtin for formats, the reference operator for references, and the `qr{}` operator for regexes.

There are language constructs in Perl that are not first-class entities and cannot be assigned to scalars or other first-class entities. For example, packages. This code doesn't work:

```
my $anonymous_package = package { ... };  # XXX
```

Shell commands have their own builtins, but are no data objects, so this won't work:

```
# don't execute `yes`, but store a handle to it in reference
my $shell_command = \qx{yes};
```

Instead, this statement should not terminate (and probably blow your memory).

Lists in Perl are language constructs, but no data types:

```
my $listref = \($x, $y, $z); # assigns reference to $z instead
```

The builtin types in Perl can have coercion rules:

- Numbers and Strings coerce back and forth.
- A single scalar in list context is a list of arity 1.
- An array in scalar context evaluates to the length of the array
- An (even valued) array can be assigned to a hash
- A Hash can be assigned to an array so that assigning this array to another hash would recreate the same hash
- A Hash in scalar context evaluates to (a) a false value if it is empty or (b) to a string indicating the number of filled and allocated buckets e.g. `1/8` or (c) to the number of keys in numerical context.
- Regexes in string context evaluate to a pattern string that behaves like the one they were specified with: `qr(ab?c) eq "(?-xism:ab?c)"`, depending on the version of perl.

Objects can be overloaded to show similar coercion rules through overloading.

In the case of regex-refs, a scalar containing such a reference can be used interchangeably with a regex literal, e.g. in the pattern

```
$string =~ /ab?c/
```

the regex could be replaced with `$regex` if `$regex` is like above:

```
my $regex = qr/ab?c/;
$string =~ $regex ### no dereferencing syntax!
# $string =~ /$regex/ will work too, but may invoke string overloading first (?)
```

For example, coderefs require more biolerplate code:

```
sub foo {...}
foo();
```

versus

```
my $foo = sub {...};
$foo->();  # two possibilities
&$foo();
```

Comment: Superb answer. Completely answered and clarified even further. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The [release notes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html) for Perl 5.12 include the following:

> REGEXPs are now first class
>
> Internally, Perl now treats compiled regular expressions (such as those created with qr//) as first class entities. Perl modules which serialize, deserialize or otherwise have deep interaction with Perl's internal data structures need to be updated for this change. Most affected CPAN modules have already been updated as of this writing.

Before 5.12, only the regex engine knew anything about compiled regexes. When you stored a compiled regexp in a scalar, you stored (a reference to) a wrapper that contained a pointer to the compiled regex pattern.

```
# 5.10.1
> perl -MDevel::Peek -e"Dump qr/abc/"
SV = RV(0x3be060) at 0x3be050
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x3be0b0
  SV = PVMG(0x2bbfd8) at 0x3be0b0     <--- Uses a generic magic scalar
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (OBJECT,SMG)
    IV = 0
    NV = 0
    PV = 0
    MAGIC = 0x262aa8
      MG_VIRTUAL = 0x28199d00
      MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_qr(r)
      MG_OBJ = 0x2bdd68           <---- Regex is actually stored
        PAT = "(?-xism:abc)"            outside the scalar.
        REFCNT = 2
    STASH = 0x3bead0    "Regexp"
```

Since 5.12, they are now a proper subtype of scalars, just like integers and strings. When you store a compiled regexp in a scalar, you store (a reference to) the compiled regex pattern itself.

```
# 5.16.1
>perl -MDevel::Peek -e"Dump qr/abc/"
SV = IV(0x74b1b8) at 0x74b1bc
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x74b1cc
  SV = REGEXP(0x33b8a4) at 0x74b1cc   <--- REGEXP is a subtype of scalar
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (OBJECT,POK,FAKE,pPOK)
    PV = 0x31f90c "(?^:abc)"
    CUR = 8
    LEN = 0
    STASH = 0x74baec    "Regexp"
    EXTFLAGS = 0x680000 (CHECK_ALL,USE_INTUIT_NOML,USE_INTUIT_ML)
    INTFLAGS = 0x0
    NPARENS = 0
    LASTPAREN = 0
    LASTCLOSEPAREN = 0
    MINLEN = 3
    MINLENRET = 3
    GOFS = 0
    PRE_PREFIX = 4
    SEEN_EVALS = 0
    SUBLEN = 0
    SUBBEG = 0x0
    ENGINE = 0x280cfac0
    MOTHER_RE = 0x328a54
    PAREN_NAMES = 0x0
    SUBSTRS = 0x326174
    PPRIVATE = 0x351c04
    OFFS = 0x74343c
```

This is what the release notes meant by "first class". I do believe the book is using amon's definition, though.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen):

> In programming language design, a first-class citizen (also object,
>   entity, or value), in the context of a particular programming
>   language, is an entity that can be constructed at run-time, passed as
>   a parameter, returned from a subroutine, or assigned into a
>   variable. In computer science the term reification is used when
>   referring to the process (technique, mechanism) of making something a
>   first-class object.
>
> An object is first-class when it:
>
> - can be stored in variables and data structures
> - can be passed as a parameter to a subroutine
> - can be returned as the result of a subroutine
> - can be constructed at run-time
> - has intrinsic identity (independent of any given name)
>
>   The term "object" is used loosely here, not necessarily referring to
>     objects in  object-oriented programming. The simplest scalar data
>     types, such as  integer and floating-point numbers, are nearly always
>     first-class.